# Obese Icon on Meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I've noticed that the inbox notification icon on Meta seems to have put on a little weight.

---

Depicted below are the icons of both sites, with the main site on top, and meta on the bottom.

[image: Inbox icon on the main site]

[image: Inbox icon on the Meta site]

Comment: Repro on IE8 on XP. Your image would probably be a lot easier to notice what you're speaking of if they were closer together and you just specified which one was on top of the other.

Comment: Good call, @GraceNote.

Comment: Repro on Chrome 12.0.742.68 beta-m on XP.

Comment: Is this really worthy of the "bug" tag? The difference seems really negligible to me.

Comment: fat icons have feelings too... yeah I'll fix. no idea why they were different to begin with.

Comment: @Oak People post bug reports about pluralization of words. This isn't all that much of a stretch. ♪

Answer (score 5):

This should be fixed in the next deployment.

Comment: EditRuiner.